# How to bind refreshing Aptana's internal web browser to a keystroke?

Tags: browser, sinatra, aptana, keystroke

Looking through Preferences --> Keys, I don't see any option for refreshing the internal web browser that I can bind a keystroke to. While there is a "Refresh" option bound to F5, it's for the file view, not the browser. As I'm working with Sinatra (and "Reloader"), once the Webrick server is started "Run" really just involves refreshing the browser view, so I would like to be able to do so without having to mouse over to the browser window.

As I'm new to Aptana (I've used Eclipse way back when, but in a different life), perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places but all my searches have been for naught at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a shortcut, for php developers it would be a miracle like F9 in a compiled language ide enviroment.